# OData routing and action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

From example on other site:

In WebApiConfig.cs

```
EntitySetConfiguration<ContactType> contactType = builder.EntitySet<ContactType>("ContactType");
var actionY = contactType.EntityType.Action("ChangePersonStatus");
actionY.Parameter<string>("Level");
actionY.Returns<bool>();

var changePersonStatusAction = contactType.EntityType.Collection.Action("ChangePersonStatus");
changePersonStatusAction.Parameter<string>("Level");
changePersonStatusAction.Returns<bool>();
```

In ContactTypeController

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("Default.ChangePersonStatus")]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePersonStatus(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
   var level = parameters["Level"];
   // SAVE THIS TO THE DATABASE OR WHATEVER....
   }
   return Ok(true);
}
```

Now the action can be called:

```
For the Entity:
http://localhost:51902/odata/ContactType(5)/Default.ChangePersonStatus
For the Entity Collection:
http://localhost:51902/odata/ContactType/Default.ChangePersonStatus
```

I don't understand how we retrieve Id = 5 of ContactType in the action and save something to database by this ID when use *..odata/ContactType(5)/Default.ChangePersonStatus* link

Answer (score 2):

**For the Entity Collection:**

```
http://localhost:51902/odata/ContactType/Default.ChangePersonStatus
```

Your method in controller should be as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("ContactType/Default.ChangePersonStatus")]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePersonStatus(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
  ...
}
```

**For the Entity:**

```
http://localhost:51902/odata/ContactType(5)/Default.ChangePersonStatus
```

Your method in controller should be as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("ContactType({key})/Default.ChangePersonStatus")]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePersonStatus(int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
  ...
}
```

*key* will have value **5**;

Comment: I tested these links in browser and both of them go to the action I wrote. Does this mean that (5) is omitted from url for the entity?

Answer (score 0):

To reference a single entity, you need to include [FromODataUri] before the key:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("ContactType({key})/Default.ChangePersonStatus")]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePersonStatus([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
  // Code
}
```

You should now be able to access your id within the method.